# Attach metadata to a stored procedure

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to attach metadata to a stored procedure in Postgres 11?

In particular, I have database migrations with version numbers. So when my migration script runs and might override the current stored proc with `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE`, I'd like to be able to attach metadata to the stored proc, with the a newer version number.

Also, how can this be queried afterwards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this there is a [`COMMENT` SQL command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-comment.html):

```
COMMENT ON PROCEDURE whatever IS 'some text'
```

To retrieve it later use the function [`obj_description()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-COMMENT-TABLE).